# SQL query to remove primary key assignment from column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for the query that does this. Tried the

```
ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT...
```

query but had no luck as it's not a constraint (i.e. the constraints directory is empty)

[image]

Comment: You can try logging what SSMS does during delete by `profiler`. That should be more interesting.

Comment: What happened when you ran the `ALTER TABLE`? What was your exact syntax? I have no problems dropping a PK using `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: Msg 3728, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
'id' is not a constraint.
Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.

Comment: As @dfundako points out, you need to use the PK name, not the column name. In the future, please include table definitions and the exact, full statement that you are using. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Likely that 'id' is NOT the name of the constraint. You have to reference it by name of the constraint, not the column name.

Comment: Tried PK_mytable_id, no luck. The constraints directory is empty.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use ALTER TABLE/DROP CONSTRAINT for a Primary Key.

Start by running sp_help on your table to get the correct PK name and confirm there is a PK on your table.  Then use your query syntax above to drop the constraint.

```
sp_help your_table_name
```

Get the 'Constraint_Name' and use

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name
DROP CONSTRAINT your_PK_Name
```